# Could not tap on UIButton in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uibutton

i  have created a view with following structure:

```
UIView (super view, freeform- width: 320, height: 1800)

.UIScrollView ( constraint: top, bottom, leading, trailing =0 )

..ContentView ( constraint: top, bottom, leading, trailing with UIScollView = 0, constraint height, width are equal to UIVIew's height, width )

...UIButton ( some red button near top of ContentView, some blue near bottom of it )
```

**Result**: I am able to tap on red buttons, but not on blue buttons.
I guess blue buttons are out of Content View.

Do you know my issue and any solution?

Comment: Add a container view inside UIScrollView as its content, since you have added a constraint with your superview, which you have set 1800, but on runtime it must be shrinking to actual screen size. So rather than increasing the superview height, add a container of height 1800 inside UIScrollView. It should work..

Comment: My container view is ContentView and width = UIView's width, height = UIView's height. is it true?

Comment: ContainerView height > UIView's height to make it scroll, right now it is all same..